# How to set value and send back to xml using XMLout function

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to change the value of xml and then set back to first one.

Here is my XML content.

```
$VAR1 = {
        'demo' => 
    '<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <cdr core-id="fefab0d8" switchname="test">
    <channel_data>
        <state>CS_REPORTING</state>
        <direction>test</direction>
        <state_number>11</state_number>
    </channel_data>
     <callflow dialplan="XML" unique-id="dba49e51" profile_index="1">
        <extension name="123456 " number="123456">
    </callflow>
    </cdr>'
 };
```

So for that I get this xml using XMLin function.

```
use XML::Simple;
my $xml = new XML::Simple;
$data = $xml->XMLin($xml123->{demo});
```

now i change the value like $data->{channel_data}->{state_number} = 12;

I use `$xml->XMLout($data);`

After changing the value i need to set back to normal xml and send this to another process.

Can any one idea how to change the value of XML without affecting its nodes ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: For starters - don't use `XML::Simple` - it's nasty.

Comment: Also: Your `XML` is invalid. Is that a typo? The `extension` tag isn't closed.

Comment: its typing mistake.sry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally achieve it using XMLout function.

While Getting an array i just added 2 parameters `"KeepRoot"=>1, ForceArray => 1`

```
$data = $xml->XMLin($xml123->{demo},`"KeepRoot"=>1, ForceArray => 1`);
```

So after that i will get proper array and then after I change back using XMLout Function.

```
$data->{demo}->[0]->{channel_data}->[0]->{state_number}->[0] = 12;


my $data1 = $xml->XMLout($data,"KeepRoot"=>1);
```

So, after this i am getting same array which I want.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

> *Can any one idea how to change the value of XML without affecting its nodes ?*

Yes, don't use XML::Simple. Its very documentation warns you against using it.

> The use of this module in new code is discouraged. Other modules are available which provide more straightforward and consistent interfaces. In particular, XML::LibXML is highly recommended.

Using XML::LibXML:

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_string($xml123->{demo});

$_->setData(12)
   for $doc->findnodes('/cdr/channel_data/state_number/text()');

$doc->toString(\*STDOUT);
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing is that XML::Simple reads a lot of things, but is not very good at reproducing the same thing back to XML. You need to set a bunch of options to achieve what you want. [But since even the XML::Simple documentation discourages its use](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Simple#STATUS-OF-THIS-MODULE), as it's rather not simple at all, I suggest to use a different XML parser.

For example, this task is easily done using [XML::Twig](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig).

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use XML::Twig;

my $twig = XML::Twig->new(
  twig_handlers => {
    state_number => sub {
      $_->set_text( $_->text + 1);
    }
  }
);
$twig->parse(\*DATA);
$twig->print;

__DATA__
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cdr core-id="fefab0d8" switchname="test">
  <channel_data>
      <state>CS_REPORTING</state>
      <direction>test</direction>
      <state_number>11</state_number>
  </channel_data>
   <callflow dialplan="XML" unique-id="dba49e51" profile_index="1">
      <extension name="123456 " number="123456" />
   </callflow>
</cdr>
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<cdr core-id="fefab0d8" switchname="test"><channel_data><state>CS_REPORTING</state><direction>test</direction><state_number>12</state_number></channel_data><callflow dialplan="XML" profile_index="1" unique-id="dba49e51"><extension name="123456 " number="123456"/></callflow></cdr>
```

Comment: Might be worth adding a `pretty_print`.

Comment: @Sobrique I decided against that because I thought for someone unfamiliar with XML::Twig it might look like its the only option. Then they'd learn to always use it, even if they are sending the XML somewhere else where no indentation is needed and where it is in fact bad because it comes with additional cost (whitespace is bytes too).